# How to update multiple columns in the same table with the same sub-query in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, sql-update, subquery

Is there a better way of writing this general type update in Oracle:

```
UPDATE table1
SET c1 = ( SELECT d1 FROM table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id ),
c2 = ( SELECT d2 FROM table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id )
```

The update above is only an example. The sub-select could be much more complex.

I see other SQL dialects have UPDATE ... SET ... FROM, but this does not seem to be in Oracle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can update multiple columns in one go:

```
drop table t1;
drop table t2;

create table t1 (col1 number, col2 number, col3 number);

create table t2 (col1 number, col2 number, col3 number);

insert into t1 values (1, 10, 100);
insert into t1 values (2, 20, 200);

insert into t2 values (1, 100, 1000);
insert into t2 values (2, 200, 2000);

commit;

update t1
set (col2, col3) = (select col2, col3 from t2 where t2.col1 = t1.col1);

commit;

select * from t1;

      COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100       1000
         2        200       2000
```

Comment: Thanks. One to add to techonthenet.

Comment: Bonus question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082145/how-to-handle-no-rows-returned-in-an-oracle-update-using-a-common-sub-select